# Incorrect connections number

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I wrote a very simple script just to retrieve list of connected users.

```
var app, io, server;

app = require("express")();
server = require("http").createServer(app);
io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(1339);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

console.log('INIT', io.sockets.manager.server.connections);

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log('CONNECT: ', io.sockets.manager.server.connections);
  socket.on("disconnect", function(data) {
    console.log('DISCONNECT: ', io.sockets.manager.server.connections);
  });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1339');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run app I get `0` on init, but as soon as I open the page in the browser it gives me `4` connections instead of just `1`. Also I get a `connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method` warning. I am using node in v0.10.15 and socket.io in v0.9.16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to obtain the number of clients from a different location:

```
 io.sockets.clients().length
```

However, when you read [this active GitHub issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/463), you might want to avoid that operation as it can cause an additional memory leak (beyond what's already happening with sockets).

Here's a complete working example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1339);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

/*
    to obtain number of connected clients
        io.sockets.clients().length            
 */

console.log("INIT", io.sockets.clients().length );

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("CONNECT:" + io.sockets.clients().length);
    socket.on("disconnect", function(data){
        console.log("DISCONNECT: ", io.sockets.clients().length);
    });
});
```

The disconnect event happens before the client has been removed, so the count will be one higher than the total number of clients (depending on how you look at it).

Also, you had the `on` event handlers returning values for some reason, so I removed that.

Instead of using that function, you might have better luck with just a simple counter:

```
var clientsConnected = 0;

console.log("INIT", io.sockets.clients().length );

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("CONNECT:" + ++clientsConnected);
    socket.on("disconnect", function(data){
        console.log("DISCONNECT: ", --clientsConnected);
    });
});
```

Some have apparently reported that the number of disconnects can exceed the number of connections, so you may want to prevent a counter from dropping below zero.

Connected two clients (and then disconnected one):

```
info: socket.io started
INIT 0
debug: served static content /socket.io.js
debug: client authorized
info: handshake authorized eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
debug: set heartbeat interval for client eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
debug: client authorized for 
debug: websocket writing 1::
CONNECT:1
debug: served static content /socket.io.js
debug: client authorized
info: handshake authorized 28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
debug: set heartbeat interval for client 28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
debug: client authorized for 
debug: websocket writing 1::
CONNECT:2
info: transport end (socket end)
debug: set close timeout for client 28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
debug: cleared close timeout for client 28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client 28lUudTS3KtCphd0Q6rP
DISCONNECT:  2
debug: discarding transport
info: transport end (socket end)
debug: set close timeout for client eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
debug: cleared close timeout for client eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client eJcvVsr60fmRzhVpQ6rO
DISCONNECT:  1
debug: discarding transport
```